# Is "o" in "hot" pronounced the same as "u" in "but" in American spoken english?

Tags: pronunciation

I heard lots of American people pronounce "o" in "hot" pronounce the same way as "u" in "but", does "o" in "hot" pronounce the same as "u" in "but" in American spoken english?

Note: I am talking about everyday spoken english.

For example: [youtu.be/rEnMEDo8Nzw?t=31](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEnMEDo8Nzw&feature=youtu.be&t=31)

Comment: [Is x pronounced y, not does]

Comment: If you've heard people pronounce it that way, then obviously people pronounce it that way...But I'm doubtful that you're hearing correctly.  Do you have an audio recording you can share with us that demonstrates this pronunciation?

Comment: @Juhasz Thanks for your remider. Here we go. https://youtu.be/rEnMEDo8Nzw?t=31

Comment: Two words I hear in the video that sound unlike American spoke English are _warm_ and _pull_.  I would maybe compare them to an Irish accent. There's a slight lilt in _warm_ and in sounds more like _worm_, and  _pull_  sounds more like _pool_

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the speaker in the linked video says neither [hɑːt]<sup>1</sup> (the typical American pronunciation of "hot") nor [hʌt]<sup>2</sup> (which would be "hut" and would rhyme with "but").  Rather, she seems to say [hat]<sup>3</sup>.

This isn't a commonly recognized feature of any American accent that I'm aware of. That speaker also has some other slightly odd pronunciations, for instance, almost lapsing into a lisp at times. However, these pronunciations are only slightly different than General American English. They are not enough to mark her as having any obviously non-standard accent.

---

Recordings:

1. https://myefe.com/transcription-pronunciation/hot
2. https://myefe.com/transcription-pronunciation/hut
3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:En-uk-hat.ogg

Answer (score 0):

No, they're not pronounced the same. "Hot" rhymes with "bot" and "not," and "but" rhymes with "hut" and "nut."